# Drage Event in android error

Tags: android, bitmap, imageview, android-custom-view, dragenter

I am using DrageEvent and TouchEvent on Custom Build View in andriod.. TouchEvent in running absolutely well.. But DrageEvent has error..   i want to get Xand Y axis on ACTION_DROP.. but only few part of imageView,when i drop in that portion ,Action)drop calls...If i drop to ather portion of sam custom ImageView..ONly Action_Drag_End calls..Action_drop does not calls here...

This is the part of code where action dop will be handeled in Custom View...

```
           public boolean onDragEvent(DragEvent event) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub  
     switch (event.getAction()) {

     case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_STARTED:

                 break;
      case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENTERED:        
          break;

      case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_EXITED:
                  break;

      case DragEvent.ACTION_DROP:
             Log.v("asf","x="+event.getX()+"+Y="+event.getY());
                       break;
      case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENDED:

           default:
                break;
}
     return true;
}
```